# Non linear second order ordinary differential equation in general relativity

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I am working on general relativity, and the so called Bonnor's model, published in 1989 (General Relativity and Gravitation Vol 21 # 11 , 1989 Negative mass in general relativity ).

From the differential equation

```
-1 + s'[t]^2 + 2 s[t] s''[t] == 0
```

he found without explanations in 1989 the following general parametric solution

```
s[u] == a^2 Cosh[u]^2
t + t0 == a^2 (1/2 Sinh[2 u] + u)
```

I am trying to get this brilliant  solution , but i am unable to find this from scratch using Mathematica 12. For example , a particular solution obtained is :

```
S = InverseFunction[(
Sqrt[#1] (1 + #1) - ArcSinh[ Sqrt[#1]] Sqrt[1 + #1])/Sqrt[
1 + #1] &];
```

But making some plot( in blue, Bonnor's solution , in red , MM12 solution) it does not give Bonnor's solution.
[image: In blue, Bonnor's solution , in red , MM12 solution]

What is wrong ? Any idea to obtain Bonnor solution with Mathematica ? Thanks a lot

PS : MM12 obtains the numerical solution, no problem, but I really would like to have the analytic solution !

Comment: Thank you JDP ! But how to find        s[u] == a^2 Cosh[u]^2
t + t0 == a^2 (1/2 Sinh[2 u] + u) ? And as you see, the plot above doesn't fit this solution.....

Comment: What are the values of `t0 , a`?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the previous comments in order to tidy up the question; the relevant information in the comments is in the answer below.

Mathematica version 13.2.1 gives a mostly equivalent result to v12, but in a slightly different form:

```
DSolve[{-1 + s'[t]^2 + 2 s[t] s''[t] == 0}, s, t]
```

[image]

The two solutions differ by a sign inside InverseFunction. I will work with the first solution here. One thing I noticed is that the Log term is the form of ArcSinh[#1] for #1 > 0. I started by extracting the anonymous function inside InverseFunction. Call it 'g' for brevity.

```
g = -E^(2 C[1]) Log[-Sqrt[#1] + Sqrt[E^(2 C[1]) + #1]] - 
   Sqrt[#1] Sqrt[E^(2 C[1]) + #1] &
```

[image]

After staring at this expression for awhile, I set up a function to allow me to run trials by varying $c_1$ and the operand. I ran FullSimplify on the results requiring u>0, since the identity I mentioned earlier only holds for arguments satisfying that condition.

```
trials[z_, c1_] :=
  FullSimplify[-E^(2 C[1]) Log[-Sqrt[#1] + Sqrt[E^(2 C[1]) + #1]] - 
       Sqrt[#1] Sqrt[E^(2 C[1]) + #1] &@z /. C[1] -> c1, u > 0];
```

I initially set C[0] = 0 to set the Exp[2 C[0]] term to 1, then started with simple trial functions. Eventually I found that inputting -Cosh[u]^2 gave me something closely resembling one of Bonnor's equations:

```
trials[- Cosh[u]^2, 0]
```

[image]

Note that Cosh[u] Sinh[u] = 1/2 Sinh[u]^2. At the time, I'd temporarily forgotten what his solution was. Upon scrolling up, I found that the input and result are close to what he got, but there are a few differences. There's an extra I Pi/2 term in the output of trials, an extra minus sign in front of Cosh[u]^2, and I haven't dealt with the a^2 terms yet. However, I have the freedom to choose two complex values constants in the solution. My initial choice for $c_0$ can be adjusted to generate an a^2 with the correct sign, and I can choose $c_2$ to yield t0 and a I Pi/2 term to cancel the one above. I also have the freedom to choose t negative, which is necessary to get all the signs flipped around so that my solution matches his.

Now, what I've done so far tells me what 'g' does. The solution for s is InverseFunction[g[#1]]. If g maps an input of -Cosh[x]^2 to x + Sinh[x] Cosh[x] + stuff, then the inverse of g reverses the role of input and output. I.e. it maps x + Sinh[x] Cosh[x] + ... to -Cosh[x]^2. Mathematica can't generate a closed form expression for this nonlinear transcendental expression, but it can solve it numerically.

The original equation returned s[t]. For a given numerical value t, pass it to the InverseFunction and add $c_2$. Relate this t+$c_2$ term to the u + Sinh[u] Cosh[u] + ... by defining an equality. This is Bonnor's reparameterization of t to u. Given t, compute the corresponding u numerically. u[t] is monotonically increasing with t, so it's a valid rescaling in general relativity. Having obtained u[t], s[u[t]] = s[u] = InverseFunction[g..] maps to Cosh[u]^2.

What remains is to choose the two constants properly. It's a bit tricky, but I was able to get all the signs to work out by choosing -b^2 Cosh[u]^2 as my input function, and $c_1$ = Log[b]. I then flipped used b^2 -> -a^2:

```
step1 = PowerExpand[
  FullSimplify[trials[-b^2 Cosh[u]^2, Log[ b]], 
    Assumptions -> u > 0] /. b^2 -> -a^2]
```

[image]

Now I come to the reason why I need to use negative t. The difference between step1 and -a^2 (u + Sinh[2u]/2) involves constants - no u dependence - but has the wrong sign with respect to Bonnor's equation.

```
step2 = FullSimplify[step1 - (-a^2 (Sinh[2 u]/2 + u)), u > 0]
```

[image]

Using -t -t0 + the residual term from steps, I can cancel out the extra term and am left with t+t0. This should fix all the signs to match his, unless I screwed up somewhere.

```
step2 - (-t - t0 + a^2 (I Pi + Log[a])) // Simplify
```

[image]

I also tried using the recent DSolveChangeVariables function to rewrite the equation in terms of s,u, but it's a complete mess and DSolve just returns unevaluated after chugging away for a while.

Although this approach does indicate Bonnor's solution is contained within Mathematica's result, is there a clever way to steer DSolve to yield it more directly? I don't know. I suspect DSolve treats this equation as part of a general class and uses a generic algorithm to generate the result. Because the expressions can't easily be inverted to a closed form, it leaves things in a form convenient for numerical processing, but doesn't find this symbolic form. So I don't see a way to automate this, though I could of course be mistaken.

One further comment regarding the plot. You didn't provide the code, but if you wish to compare solutions, you need to convert 't' to 'u' by numerically solving Bonnor's nonlinear 2nd equation in order to plot his solution and compare to Mathematica's, which is in terms of t, not u. Parameters t,u are related, but different.

Answer (score 0):

In the classical setting of the math curriculum, this is an challenging exercise in ODE theory, because of having the idea. The execution is trivial.

Set the  equation

```
eq = s'[t]^2 + 2 s[t] s''[t] == 1;
```

Use Leibniz calculus to solve the coupled system of first order for a convenient pair of differentials with

s' -> u ,  u' ->  ds/dt

```
eq1 = { eq, ds/dt == u} /. {s'[t] :> ds/dt, s''[t] :> du/dt , s[t] :> s}

{ds^2/dt^2 + (2 du s)/dt == 1, ds/dt == u}

eq2 = Equal @@@ Solve[eq1 /. {dt -> t'[s] ds, du -> u'[s] ds, u -> u[s], 
  t -> t[s]}, {t'[s], u'[s]}][[1]]

sol = DSolve[eq2, {t, u}, s] /. Exp[2 C[1]] -> s0



 {{u -> Function[{s}, -(Sqrt[s0 + s]/Sqrt[s])], 
t -> Function[{s}, Sqrt[s] Sqrt[s0 + s] + C[2]-s0 Log[-Sqrt[s] + Sqrt[s0 + s]]]}, 
{u -> Function[{s}, Sqrt[s0 + s]/Sqrt[s]], 
  t -> Function[{s}, Sqrt[s] Sqrt[s0 + s] + C[2] + s0 Log[-Sqrt[s] + Sqrt[s0 + s]]]}}
```

Never forget to check solutions

```
  eq2 /. sol // Simplify

{{True, True}, {True, True}}



    Eliminate[{u^2 ==  (p + s )/s, 
  t == Sqrt[s] Sqrt[p + s] + t0 + p Log[-Sqrt[s] + Sqrt[p + s]]}, u]

  -Sqrt[s] Sqrt[p + s] + t - t0 - 
   p Log[-Sqrt[s] + Sqrt[p + s]] == 0 && s != 0
```

How to get from here to the cosh^2-parametrization is an algebraic problem  of dealing with the log algebra.

Except for the engineering community, there exisits no rule for all applications, because the complex log has this branch point at zero with indefintely many leafs. They may be glued together as the actual painter likes it, so its a kind of art.

It often helps in such cases to  square  dentities as I did here for U^2 and try to transform logarithmic identies to exponential identities, that suppress the branch lines. The typical probelm is e.g.

```
a_ Log[b_]+c_ Log[d_] :> Log[b^a d^-c]
```

in order to get

```
ArcTanh[x] // TrigToExp ==Log[((1- x) /(1+x))^1(2]
```